# Does SwiftUI button have border by default?

Tags: swiftui

I am using Xcode to create an app that requires buttons. Right now, when I create a button, I get the text label, which I want, but I also get a background with rounded corners around it. I want to have the button with just the label but without the background. I was using Swift Playgrounds before Xcode and did not have this problem.
Here is my code:

```
import SwiftUI

struct ContentView: View {
    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            Rectangle()
                .frame(width: 1000, height: 500)
                .foregroundColor(.red)
            Button(action: {
                
            }) {
                Text("Button")
            }

        }
    }
}
```

[image: This is what my button looks like]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Customize the button's style with the `.buttonStyle` view modifier:

```swift
Button(action: {}) {
    Text("Button")
}
.buttonStyle(.borderless)
```

`.borderless`, `.plain`, and `.link` are the options that will result in no border.

Comment: Thank you! Do buttons in Xcode have borders by default?

Comment: On macOS, yes, but on iOS, no.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a `Button` without any background or border.

```
Button("Click") {
    //do something
}
.background(.clear) //this
```

[image]

Comment: This seems to work only on iOS, where buttons by default have no border or background (you can actually omit the `.background(.clear)` and get the same appearance on iOS).

Comment: @McKinley I actually ran this on `My Mac` simulator